# How to access firebase array

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to access fingerprint array in Android? I don't know what to do.

```
DatabaseReference dbTITO = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Employee/2/fingerprint");
dbTITO.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)  {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            byte[] imageFinger = dataSnapshot.child("fingerprint").getValue();

        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obQMK.png)
Employee 2
code: 2
department_name: "Assasin                       "
fingerprint
0: 0
1: 248
2: 126
3: 1
4: 200
5: 42
6: 227

Comment: Please provide database screenshot instead of providing database structure

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, I include a picture. Is this it? or do you need the path?

Comment: The fingerprint is a array of bytes()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are using a reference like this `Employee/2/fingerprint`, there is no need to call `child("fingerprint")` again. To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference fingerprintRef = rootRef.child("Employee").child("2").child("fingerprint");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) count];
        int count = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long value = ds.getValue(Long.class);
            bytes[count] = (byte) value;
            count++;
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your array
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
fingerprintRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```